# What's the copyright status of boilerplate code?

Tags: open-source, language-agnostic, copyright

I check Open Source Compliance for commercial code.

I have recently found a few examples where the commercial source is matched against quite a few OSS projects. The matches are very similar, but not exact, say about 30 lines of code with about 4 methods, a few variables names differ, some extra lines in the commercial code, ... but substantially the same. I don't think this is auto-generated code, nor copy-pasta, because things like comments will differ.

Rather it just looks like boilerplate - the developers say that Grails (and these examples always seem to come up in Grails, but it could be any framework) requires a specific script format for CRUD operations (and these examples are also predominantly CRUD operations). If one adds in a standard source-code style, then it amounts to boilerplate - even if it is original it's going to end up as very similar looking across a number of codebases.

Which leaves me with 2 questions:

1. Is this a reasonable defence against accusations of copyright infringement?
2. How would one form a judgement that codeX is such boilerplate, but codeY is not (as a non-expert in the language+framework)?

Comment: The fewer lines of code needed to complete a task, the likelier that different original implementations will be the same.  If asked to sum all elements in an array, pretty much everybody is going to use a loop with an externally defined variable to hold the running total.  There's two major directions to take a factorial function.  The code submitted for things like Code Chef might be interesting to examine here - for all distinct (correct!) results, run a diff.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer.

This is part of the [idea/expression divide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_divide). The short form is that ideas cannot be copyrighted, only their expression can. And if the idea has only one (or a small number of) expressions, those expressions can't be copyrighted.

Whether or not this can be used as an infringement defense depends on jurisdiction and/or legal precedents.